# How do I make a whole Div a Button?

Tags: javascript, php, html

First I made a link of the whole div

```
<a href=''><div></div></a>
```

Its clickable and everything but with this I cant Submit a POST which I want to do so im trying to make the whole div a button(and then make it transparent) But the button doesnt fill the whole div and the buttons placement aint in the whole div but outside the div.

```
<button><div></div></button>
```

**How do I make the WHOLE div a button?**

---

@Rodrigo Leite

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      //test
header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
}

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/sprinkle.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div_test').click(function(){
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});

  </script>

<form name='form' action='' method='POST'><div id='div_test' ></div></form>
```

Comment: I want a form to submit something

Comment: if the "button" is pressed some php code will run.

Comment: Check the answer I just posted. Create two pages. One index.html and one action_page.php and just copy and paste the code in and it should work fine. Have you installed a mamp xamp or wamp on your computer? you have to install php for it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, using javascript:

```
<?php

$name = @$_POST['name'];
$lastName = @$_POST['lastName'];

echo 'Received data:<br>';
echo $name . ' ' . $lastName;
echo '<br><br>';

?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='' method='post' id='form'>
        Name: <input type='text' name='name'><br>
        Last name: <input type='text' name='lastName'<br>
        <br><br>
        <div onclick='$("#form").submit();' style='border: 1px solid #000000'>
            DIV example: Fire form submit on click</div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit butto e.g.'>
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: You used a selector #form but not defined a id to the form. Change this: <form name='form' to this: <form id='form' name='form' I edited my post. Take a look.

Comment: hm i get: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jquery-1.2.6.min.js:1:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js:1:0
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' sprinkle.js:1:0
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Well, if I undestood correctly, you want to fire a submit when you click on a DIV, this code does that. But, you have to create the server side code that will receive your post data and insert in the form your fields..

Comment: Ive done the serverside but something is wrong somewhere :S

Comment: I edited my post one more time with the HTML, JS and PHP example. Take a look if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a post to a page you will need a form that has the post method.

index.html

```
<form action="action_page.php" id="myNames" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="myName">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="myLastName">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then recieve the information that is posted by a `php` file.

action_page.php

```
$firstName = $_POST['myName'];
$lastName = $_POST['myLastName'];

echo $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
```

To submit a form with `javascript`

```
<div class="button" id="SubmitForm" onclick="submitForm()" title="myNames">

 function submitForm()
 {
      document.getElementById('myNames').submit();
 }
```

Now when you click the div with the `id="SubmitForm"` the for, will be submitted. Notice the id of each element. This is how we are selecting each element.

Then with our php when we get to the php page we use the name of each element to convert to a php variable and echo it back.

Comment: Please see the edit I forgot to add post to the form. It is there now.

Comment: But how do i trigger the POST by pressing a div?

Comment: If you want a div to submit a form you need to use javascript. You want a whole div to be clickable instead of having a submit ?

Comment: I want a submit form to be run when the div is clicked.